# Problem in serialization "scala.math.BigDecimal does not have a no-arg default constructor"

Tags: scala, jaxb, bigdecimal

I'm new to scala programming and java so here is my problem:

I have an object to be serialized with a BigDecimal Property

```
import java.util.Date
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter
import reflect.BeanProperty

class TestObject {
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(classOf[BigDecimalAdapter])
  var test: BigDecimal = 0.00
}
```

I receive this error:

```
scala.math.BigDecimal does not have a no-arg default constructor
```

XmlAdapter:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter

class BigDecimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter[String, BigDecimal] {
  def unmarshal(str: String) = BigDecimal(str)
  def marshal(bD: BigDecimal) = bD.toString()
}
```

SOAPServer:

```
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding
import javax.jws.{WebParam, WebMethod, WebService}
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint

@WebService(targetNamespace="test", name="testws", portName="test", serviceName="wsTest")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
class Server {
  @WebMethod(action = "test")
  def test(@WebParam(name = "testParam") testParam:TestObject): TestObject = {
    return testParam
  }

}

object SoapServer { // defined Companion Object for our class
  def main(args: Array[String]) { // main method to make this a runnable application
    val endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://192.168.189.132:8080/wsTest", new Server())
    System.out.println("Binded to port 8080. Waiting for requests...")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to be using `java.math.BigDecimal`, as opposed to `scala.math.BigDecimal`. Use the fully-qualified path name:

```
 import java.math.{BigDecimal => JDec}
 var test: JDec = new JDec(0)
```

It seems like the jaxb framework is expecting a no-arg constructor; I'm not familiar enogh with it to understand why

Comment: This solution corrected the problem. Just for completeness, what are the differences between the version from java and the scala one?

Comment: Well, the scala one is of the classic "pimp my library" pattern, where you can use standard math symbols (`+ * - /`) as operators. Also there is a `Numeric[BigDecimal]` so you can do things like `myObjs.map(_.test).sum` etc. You can also interop with other numbers; for example `myObj.test == 0` sensibly